# How to say "100% virus free"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, business-japanese, english-to-japanese, copywriting

In English we put the following phrases below software we want customers to download to put their mind at ease (for example, a neat weather app).

- ✓100% virus free
- ✓Contains no malware
- ✓Contains no spyware
- ✓Certified adware free
- ✓This file is clean and safe

etc.

What is an equivalent phrase in Japanese (not literal translations, but a phrase *actually used* in practice)?

Something like "✓ウイルス等が検出されませんでした", but more optimistic and reassuring.

Note: Searching for a live example has proven fruitless as Google searches lead to anti-virus software, not "clean" downloads.

Comment: Well, [here](http://proxifier.ja.downloadastro.com/antivirus-results/) is some page I found that says "ウイルスなし" but it doesn't seem to be a very popular phrase according to Google. It is possible that they don't really have an expression like this... It's kind of a weird thing to say anyway, similar to "Buy our TVs! They don't explode when you turn them on!". Like, of course you're supposed to release products that won't ruin people's computers.

Comment: I think you're not in a hurry until some anti-virus softwares misdetect your program. And there's no widely known certification in Japan on malware-freeness AFAIK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ウイルス等が検出されませんでした sounds more like "No virus were detected", which is different from "Virus-free".

The first thing I'd like to mention is that most sophisticated Japanese e-commerce sites do not say anything like this in their download pages, at least in a large font. To me, saying "virus free" loudly already smells like typical foreign sites (some of which are actually risky) built by non-native speakers of Japanese.

That said, perhaps the most natural wording would be "ウイルスチェック済み" (lit. "virus check performed"), "マルウェア・スパイウェアを一切含んでいません" (lit. "contains no malware/spyware"), etc.

Some sites do say something like "複数のセキュリティソフトで検査した上でソフトを公開しています" ("We host software after checking it using more than one security solutions") in a relatively small font.

Comment: The Japanese around here are liking "ウイルスチェック済み" the best. Thanks Naruto.

Answer (score 5):

Using a word なし seems to be a common way in Japanese, if a company or a developer team provides this kind of information.

For example, [a Japanese webpage about a software called AOMEI Buckupper](http://www.backup-utility.com/jp/free-trial.html) uses this expression.

> 100％クリーンのインストール： スパイウェアなし、アドウェアなし、**ウィルスなし**！ご安心ください。

In [the English webpage of this](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-trial.html), it says

> 100% Clean Installation: NO SPYWARE, NO ADWARE, NO VIRUSES! Please set your mind at rest.

As shown, literally, it’s a little different from your phrases, but I think the purpose is the same, so hope it helps.

Some websites use 無し instead of なし. For example, [a webpage about Avant Browser](http://www.avantbrowser.com/default.aspx?uil=ja) uses the following expression.

> 広告無し、**ウイルス無し**、スパイウェア無し、マルウェア無し！

So, a phrase actually used in practice is ウイルスなし or ウイルス無し in many cases.

If you’d like to know more, please try some Japanese version websites of other softwares. Their translation may be helpful.

Comment: +1 For translating the phrases in the question. "広告無し" was liked. The people around here say, upon seeing this thread, that "ウイルスチェック済み" is smoothest. FWIW, being a Westerner, I feel more at home with your translations above. Thanks.